# How to use this library with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to use this library https://github.com/axet/vget

I can't seem to figure out how to get a .jar file out of that so I can use it.

Comment: simple: download code, import into eclipse workspace as new project, reference the new project from your project. Alternately use maven eclipse plugin.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not with this one since the zip file is an archive of source files. The OP will have to extract, build and then bundle into a JAR file.

Comment: @adarshr: you appear to be right. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can put the below dependency in your pom.xml if you use Maven.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
  <artifactId>vget</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, you could download the archive from https://github.com/axet/vget/releases and build it yourself.

If you want the latest (unreleased) version, you'll have to clone the repository on your machine and build it yourself.

Comment: How do you use maven with eclipse? I'm still in highschool using BlueJ, so I'm really new to Eclipse.